# How to install C source files and headers?

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I've been given [these](https://github.com/pq-crystals/dilithium) source files and headers. In the README.md the authors explain how to launch the test executables without the need of a proper installation. It is just a `make` command to run. They explain how to generate the `.so` files. I think these latter are meant to be used if I wanted to install the APIs at a system level (the definitions should be in `api.h`). My question is: where should I copy the shared objects generated by the Makefile and the `api.h` header? I aim to write a source file from scratch where I use those APIs (e.g. `crypto_sign()`) just including the headers, if it is possible. Thanks

Comment: Makefiles usually have an `install` option. See you have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where should I copy the shared objects generated by the Makefile and the api.h header? I aim to write a source file from scratch where I use those APIs (e.g. crypto_sign()) just including the headers, if it is possible

Nowhere.

The project comes with CMake support. Use CMake in your project and just `add_subdirectory` the repository directory.

Anyway, if you really wish to install the library system-wide, then [FHS](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html) specifies directory structure on linux. For local system administration use `/usr/local/lib` for local libraries `.so` files and `/usr/local/include` for local C header files.

Comment: Never used CMake unfortunatelly. If you don't mind could you tell me what I should do?

Comment: If you intent to work in C, then learn cmake. It's nowadays I believe the most popular build system for C environment.

Comment: Can you link some good reference? Books, online tutorials, YouTube videos, whatever as long as you deem it valid